# ReactiveSwift: How to observe UIView isHidden?

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa

I'd like to show `B` UIView iff `A` UIView is visible. I used ReactiveCocoa 2 in objective-c and tried to find a similar way to observe `isHidden` property of UIView in `ReactiveSwift`. I'm still trying to learn the framework and its usage, but couldn't come up with a good solution. I'd appreciate if anyone can give me an advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the KVO example from the [ReactiveSwift readme](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/README.md):

```
// A producer that sends the current value of `keyPath`, followed by
// subsequent changes.
//
// Terminate the KVO observation if the lifetime of `self` ends.
let producer = object.reactive.values(forKeyPath: #keyPath(key))
    .take(during: self.reactive.lifetime)
```

So in your case you can do something like this (haven't actually tried this code, but it should convey the idea):

```
viewA.reactive.values(forKeyPath: #keyPath(isHidden))
    .take(during: self.reactive.lifetime)
    .startWithValues { hidden in viewB.isHidden = hidden }
```

UPDATE:

I just noticed that ReactiveCocoa [includes a binding target for UIView`s isHidden property](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoa/UIKit/UIView.swift), so you can actually simplify the above code to:

```
viewB.reactive.isHidden <~ viewA.reactive.values(forKeyPath: #keyPath(isHidden))
```

Note that the `take(during:)` is no longer necessary when using `<~`, as `<~` automatically ties disposal of the binding source to the lifetime of the binding target.